# banking style title and classic body in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I am trying to create my CV in latex based on some basic designs(`moderncv`) given in the following link:
[link](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/moderncv-cv-and-cover-letter)
How do I create a CV with `banking` style for title and `classic` style for the body ?

I copied the following from `moderncvstylebanking.sty` and put it before `\begin{document}`

```
\makeatletter

% symbols
\renewcommand*{\mobilesymbol}{\marvosymbol{72}~}
\renewcommand*{\phonesymbol}{\marvosymbol{84}~}
\renewcommand*{\faxsymbol}{\marvosymbol{117}~}
\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}{\marvosymbol{66}~}
\renewcommand*{\homepagesymbol}{{\Large\marvosymbol{205}}~}

% commands
\newcommand*{\maketitlesymbol}{%
{~~~{\rmfamily\textbullet}~~~}}% the \rmfamily is required to force Latin Modern fonts when using sans serif, as OMS/lmss/m/n is not defined and gets substituted by OMS/cmsy/m/n
%   internal command to add an element to the footer
%   it collects the elements in a temporary box, and checks when to flush the box
\newsavebox{\maketitlebox}%
\newsavebox{\maketitletempbox}%
\newlength{\maketitlewidth}%
\newlength{\maketitleboxwidth}%
\newif\if@firstmaketitleelement\@firstmaketitleelementtrue%
%   adds an element to the maketitle, separated by maketitlesymbol
%   usage: \addtomaketitle[maketitlesymbol]{element}
\newcommand*{\addtomaketitle}[2][\maketitlesymbol]{%
  \if@firstmaketitleelement%
    \savebox{\maketitletempbox}{\usebox{\maketitlebox}#2}%
  \else%
    \savebox{\maketitletempbox}{\usebox{\maketitlebox}#1#2}\fi%
  \settowidth{\maketitleboxwidth}{\usebox{\maketitletempbox}}%
  \ifnum\maketitleboxwidth<\maketitlewidth%
    \savebox{\maketitlebox}{\usebox{\maketitletempbox}}%
    \@firstmaketitleelementfalse%
  \else%
    \flushmaketitle{}\\%
    \savebox{\maketitlebox}{#2}%
    \savebox{\maketitletempbox}{#2}%
    \settowidth{\maketitleboxwidth}{\usebox{\maketitlebox}}%
    \@firstmaketitleelementfalse\fi}
%   internal command to flush the maketitle
\newcommand*{\flushmaketitle}{%
  \strut\usebox{\maketitlebox}%
  \savebox{\maketitlebox}{}%
  \savebox{\maketitletempbox}{}%
  \setlength{\maketitleboxwidth}{0pt}}
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
  \setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \hfil%
  \parbox{\maketitlewidth}{%
    \centering%
    % name and title
    \namestyle{\@firstname~\@familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@title}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\%
    % detailed information
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}    {\addtomaketitle{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]    {\@addresscity}}\flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\}% if     \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}    {\addtomaketitle{\mobilesymbol\@mobile}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}    {\addtomaketitle{\phonesymbol\@phone}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\faxsymbol\@fax}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}    {\addtomaketitle{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@homepagetitle}{}}% \homepagetitle could be empty
{\addtomaketitle{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
{\addtomaketitle{\homepagesymbol\httplink[\@homepagetitle]    {\@homepage}}}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}    {\addtomaketitle{\@extrainfo}}%
    \flushmaketitle}\\[2.5em]}% need to force a \par after this to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                resume style definition
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% fonts
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\Huge\bfseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\Huge\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\normalsize\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\bfseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\upshape\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{\bfseries}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2!85}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}

% lengths
\newlength{\quotewidth}
\newlength{\hintscolumnwidth}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.3\textwidth}%
\newlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}
\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.025\textwidth}%
\newlength{\maincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}
\newlength{\listitemsymbolwidth}
\settowidth{\listitemsymbolwidth}{\listitemsymbol}
\newlength{\listitemmaincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}

% commands
\renewcommand*{\recomputecvlengths}{%
  \setlength{\quotewidth}{0.65\textwidth}%
  % main lenghts
  \setlength{\maincolumnwidth}{\textwidth}%
  % listitem lengths
  \setlength{\listitemmaincolumnwidth}{\maincolumnwidth-                \listitemsymbolwidth}%
  % doubleitem lengths
  \setlength{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}{\maincolumnwidth-    \separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \setlength{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}{0.5\doubleitemcolumnwidth}%
  % listdoubleitem lengths
  \setlength{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}{\maincolumnwidth-    \listitemsymbolwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-\listitemsymbolwidth}%
  \setlength{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}    {0.5\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}%
  % fancyhdr lengths
  \renewcommand{\headwidth}{\textwidth}%
  % regular lengths
  \setlength{\parskip}{0\p@}}

\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  \maketitle%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
{}%
{{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle}

\makeatother
```

which gives the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \quotewidth already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.96 \newlength{\quotewidth}

? 

! LaTeX Error: Command \hintscolumnwidth already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.97 \newlength{\hintscolumnwidth}

? 

! LaTeX Error: Command \separatorcolumnwidth already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.99 \newlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}

? 

! LaTeX Error: Command \maincolumnwidth already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
     ...                                              

l.101 \newlength{\maincolumnwidth}

? 

! LaTeX Error: Command \listitemsymbolwidth already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.103 \newlength{\listitemsymbolwidth}

? 

! LaTeX Error: Command \listitemmaincolumnwidth already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.105 \newlength{\listitemmaincolumnwidth}

? 

! LaTeX Error: Command \listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.106 \newlength{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}

?
```

Answer (score 2):

Class `moderncv` defines the several styles in separate `sty` files.  You have two possibilitys:

1. Create a new style and include it into moderncv. That is not easy, because you would have to change a lot of files building class `moderncv`. Easier is method two.
2. Change one of the existing styles (one you usually do not use) and add the hacked `sty` file in the same directory where your cv file, let's say `mwe-moderncv.tex`is. But please see: that is a dirty hack then!

A third possibility would be to have a inbuild-style, like `mystyle.sty`, so one can change the style as he/she wants. I think I will suggest the author of `moderncv` to do that.

I decided to use method 2, therefore I changed `oldstyle` of `moderncv`.  :

With the both lines

```
\moderncvhead{3} 
\moderncvbody{1}
```

we define that we want (1. line) the banking style title and (2. line) classic body in the hacked style. So we get the complete hacked version to

Hacked version of `moderncvstyleoldstyle.sty` (same directory that contains your cv):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{moderncvstyleoldstyle}[2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter style scheme: oldstyle hacked by John]

\DeclareOption*{}% 
%\ExecuteOptions{mixedrules,left}
\ProcessOptions*\relax% 


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                fonts & icons
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% TeX Gyre Pagella font
  \IfFileExists{tgpagella.sty}%
    {%
      \RequirePackage{tgpagella}%
      \renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}}%
    {}

% symbols
\moderncvicons{marvosym} % marvosym awesome


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                header, body & footer
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\moderncvhead{3} % <====================================================
\moderncvbody{1} % <====================================================

\endinput
```

Now we can use the hacked `sty` file in our `mwe-moderncv.tex` to create the wished CV:

```
\listfiles % to check easy the used versions
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{oldstyle} % <============== hacked version!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% 
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % 
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}


\end{document}
```

Please check in the resulting logfile that you see at the end of the log file a list of used packages and versions, containing

```
moderncvstyleoldstyle.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter style scheme: oldstyle hacked by John
```

Then the hacked version (you see **hacked by John**?) was used and you should see the following result:

[image: resulting cv]

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that

```
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvheader{3}
```

which tries to implement banking header + classic body doesn't work. But

```
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvbody{1} % classic body
```

works perfectly and gives what you're looking for. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvbody{1} % classic body

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{The title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\end{document}
```