# How to mix/combine moderncv styles?

Tags: moderncv

Can I mix `moderncv` styles, let say I want to use banking style for the header (title) definition and use classic style definitions for the rest?

Comment: Not without intense code juggling.

Comment: it would be nice if some parts are configurable `\moderncvheaderstyle` like `\moderncvheaderstyle`

Comment: You saw my answer to question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261125/banking-style-title-and-classic-body-in-moderncv/294497#294497 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into the code, in fact [banking style](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvstylebanking.sty) uses [`moderncvheadiii.sty`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvheadiii.sty) for that it loads the specific header definitions (`moderncvheadiii.sty`) using `\moderncvhead{3}`  thus one can use banking style for the header and classic style for the rest by adding that command after loading the classic style, that would overwrite the classic style loaded defintions of the header.

```
...
\moderncvstyle{classic}  
\moderncvhead{3}
...
```

Comment: looks good. :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B maybe someone else will tought about posting a generic/simplified solution for that.