# Add \photo to a mix of moderncv styles and change position

Tags: macros, graphics, positioning, moderncv

This is a follow-up question to [Banking style of moderncv doesnt reconize `\makecvheadnamewidth` for fiting long names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/317219/92620) and to [How to mix/combine moderncv styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319794/92620).

Now I am looking to add the definition of the command `\photo` to the `banking` style I already read [ModernCV Banking photo title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201144/92620) and this [How to include picture in banking style with exactly position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154383/92620) but since I have mixed styles things got confused I don't know how to make it to work.

- I want my photo besides the title not above it,
- a plus would be to choose whether to put it on the left or on the right of the header.

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\moderncvhead{3}

\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter  %to fix the issue of the long name in banking style
\xpatchcmd{\makehead}{%
\titlestyle{~|~\@title}%
}{%
\\\vspace*{10pt}\titlestyle{\@title}\vspace*{10pt}%
}{}{false}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\let\oldmakecvtitle\makecvtitle
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  {\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}\par\vspace{10pt}}%
  \oldmakecvtitle%
}%
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\nopagenumbers{}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\firstname{my long name}
\familyname{familyname}
\address{address comes here}{10000}
\phone[mobile]{00~00~00~00~00}
\email{myemail@gmail.com}
\extrainfo{xx ans Permis B}
\photo[64pt][40pt]{example-image.png}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a look into the sources of class `moderncv`.  Then you can find, that the code of header for style `classic` differes to the code of header for `banking`. In your case you need to change the code of header for `banking`.

That is the reason you have to use:

```
\patchcmd{\makehead}
  {\setlength{\makeheaddetailswidth}{0.8\textwidth}}
  {\setlength{\makeheaddetailswidth}{0.67\textwidth}}
  {}
  {false2}
\patchcmd{\makehead}% version 2.0.0, style banking, head3
  {\\[2.5em]}
  {\hfil\raisebox{-1.6cm}{\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}\\[2.5em]}
  {}
  {failure}
```

instead the changing with

```
\let\oldmakecvtitle\makecvtitle
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  {\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}\par\vspace{10pt}}%
  \oldmakecvtitle%
}%
```

you tried.

Depending on the used image you have to change the value in command `\raisebox` to your needs.

With the following complete MWE

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\moderncvhead{3} % uses header from style banking!

\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter  %to fix the issue of the long name in banking style
\patchcmd{\makehead}{%
\titlestyle{~|~\@title}%
}{%
\\\vspace*{10pt}\titlestyle{\@title}\vspace*{10pt}%
}{}{false}

\patchcmd{\makehead}
  {\setlength{\makeheaddetailswidth}{0.8\textwidth}}
  {\setlength{\makeheaddetailswidth}{0.67\textwidth}}
  {}
  {false2}
\patchcmd{\makehead}% version 2.0.0, style banking, head3
  {\\[2.5em]}
  {\hfil\raisebox{-1.6cm}{\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}\\[2.5em]}
  {}
  {failure}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\nopagenumbers{}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\firstname{my long name}
\familyname{familyname}
\address{address comes here}{10000}
\phone[mobile]{00~00~00~00~00}
\email{myemail@gmail.com}
\extrainfo{xx ans Permis B}
\photo[64pt][40pt]{example-image-10x16} % --> change \raisebox{-1.6cm}{} to your needs ...
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

you get the photo on the right side on the paper, see the following result:

[image: result photo right]

To get the photo to the left needs to rebuild the header completely using a `tabular` environment.  That is better done in a complete new header I think ...