# Combine modercv classic banking with academicons

Tags: moderncv

So i have now from tex exchange found several good answers and been able to combine the banking header with the classic body information in terms of the job listings. While also moving my picture next to the banking header information.

First the banking header and classic body is from [banking style title and classic body in moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261125/banking-style-title-and-classic-body-in-moderncv)
and moving a picture to the right with [How to include picture in banking style with exactly position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154383/how-to-include-picture-in-banking-style-with-exactly-position)

As such my current files are a moderncvstyleoldstyle.sty

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{moderncvstyleoldstyle}[2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter style scheme: oldstyle hacked by John]

\DeclareOption*{}% 
%\ExecuteOptions{mixedrules,left}
\ProcessOptions*\relax% 


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261125/banking-style-title-and-classic-body-in-moderncv 
% to use the banking style for my header (personal info) and classic style for the cv (body)


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                fonts & icons
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% TeX Gyre Pagella font
  \IfFileExists{tgpagella.sty}%
    {%
      \RequirePackage{tgpagella}%
      \renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}}%
    {}

% symbols
\moderncvicons{marvosym} % marvosym awesome


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                header, body & footer
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\moderncvhead{3} % <====================================================
\moderncvbody{1} % <====================================================


% Here i make the box such that my face is next to the information
% taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154383/how-to-include-picture-in-banking-style-with-exactly-position
\patchcmd{\makehead}
  {\hfil}
  {\hspace*{0.15\textwidth}}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\makehead}
  {\setlength{\makeheaddetailswidth}{0.8\textwidth}}
  {\setlength{\makeheaddetailswidth}{0.67\textwidth}}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\makehead}
  {\\[2.5em]}
  {\hfil\raisebox{-.7cm}{\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}\\[2.5em]}
  {}
  {}

\endinput
```

And then i add my resume

```
\listfiles % to check easy the used versions
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{oldstyle} % <============== hacked version!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}
% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% 
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % 
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}

\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}


\end{document}
```

However I also want to add under personal information

```
\social[googlescholar]{info}
\social[orcid]{info}
\social[researchgate]{info}
\social[github]{info}
```

Which I previously did using \usepackage{academicons}

However, with the changes I have made the icons dont appear anymore, and I have tried putting the package and manually defining the orcid (as an example) within the .sty file.

So can anyone help with keeping this format with the banking header (and picture to the right) and classic cv style while adding the academic social images?